# cocos2dx 3.11.1 android studio in windows

Tags: c++, windows, android-studio, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

hi i want to use cocos2dx android studio in windows.

i downloaded android-ndk-r12, android studio and apache-ant-1.9.7. cocos2dx 3.11.1

now i am successfully create a project by using command cocos.py new MyGame -p com.MyCompany.MyGame -l cpp -d I:\Work\cocos2dx.

But where i am using cocos.py compile -p android --android-studio to compile i am getting this error

[armeabi] "Compile++ thumb": "MyGame_shared <= AppDelegate.cpp"
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, I:/Software/ProgramingSoftware/cocos2dx/android-ndk-r12/build//../toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/MyGame_shared/hellocpp/ma
in.o.d -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -g -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -mthumb -O0 -UNDEBUG -Ijni/../../../Classes -II:/Software/ProgramingSoftware/cocos2dx/android
-ndk-r12/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -II:/Software/ProgramingSoftware/cocos2dx/android-ndk-r12/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi/include -II:/Software/ProgramingSoftware/cocos2dx/android-ndk-r12/build//../sources/c
xx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/editor-support/cocostudio/.. -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/editor-support/cocosbuilder/.. -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.an
droid-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/3d/.. -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/editor-support/spine/.. -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/network -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/audi
o/android/../include -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/ui/../editor-support -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/audio/android/../include -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/external/fl
atbuffers/.. -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/extensions/. -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/extensions/.. -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/extensions/GUI/CCControlExtension -II:/Work/cocos2
dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/extensions/GUI/CCScrollView -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/. -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/./. -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/coc
os/./.. -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/./../external -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/./../external/tinyxml2 -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/./../external/unzip -II:/Wo
rk/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/./../external/chipmunk/include/chipmunk -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/./../external/xxhash -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/./../external/nslo
g -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/./../external/poly2tri -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/./../external/poly2tri/common -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/./../external/pol
y2tri/sweep -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/./../external/clipper -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/external/websockets/prebuilt/android/../../include/android -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/..
/cocos2d/external/Box2D/.. -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/external/bullet/.. -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/external/freetype2/prebuilt/android/../../include/android -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-stud
io/../cocos2d/external/freetype2/prebuilt/android/../../include/android/freetype2 -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/external/png/prebuilt/android/../../include/android -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/external/jpeg
/prebuilt/android/../../include/android -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/external/tiff/prebuilt/android/../../include/android -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/external/webp/prebuilt/android/../../include/android -
II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/external/chipmunk/prebuilt/android/../../include -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/external/zlib/prebuilt/android/../../include -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos
2d/external/recast/.. -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/platform/android -II:/Software/ProgramingSoftware/cocos2dx/android-ndk-r12/build//../sources/android/cpufeatures -Ijni -DANDROID -DUSE_FILE32API -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Wer
ror=format-security -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-extern-c-compat -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS=1 -Wno-extern-c-compat -fexceptions -frtti -DCC_ENABLE_CHIPMUNK_INTEGRATION=1 -std=c++11 -fsigned-char -DCOCOS2D_DEBUG=1 -isystem I:/Software/ProgramingSoftware/cocos2dx
/android-ndk-r12/build//../platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/include -c jni/hellocpp/main.cpp -o ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/MyGame_shared/hellocpp/main.o, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/MyGame_shared/hellocpp/main.o] Error 2
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, I:/Software/ProgramingSoftware/cocos2dx/android-ndk-r12/build//../toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/MyGame_shared/**/**/**/Cl
asses/AppDelegate.o.d -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -g -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -mthumb -O0 -UNDEBUG -Ijni/../../../Classes -II:/Software/ProgramingSoftware/c
ocos2dx/android-ndk-r12/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -II:/Software/ProgramingSoftware/cocos2dx/android-ndk-r12/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi/include -II:/Software/ProgramingSoftware/cocos2dx/android-ndk-r12/buil
d//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/editor-support/cocostudio/.. -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/editor-support/cocosbuilder/.. -II:/Work/cocos2dx
/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/3d/.. -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/editor-support/spine/.. -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/network -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../coc
os2d/cocos/audio/android/../include -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/ui/../editor-support -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/audio/android/../include -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../coco
s2d/external/flatbuffers/.. -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/extensions/. -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/extensions/.. -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/extensions/GUI/CCControlExtension -
II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/extensions/GUI/CCScrollView -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/. -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/./. -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio
/../cocos2d/cocos/./.. -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/./../external -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/./../external/tinyxml2 -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/./../externa
l/unzip -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/./../external/chipmunk/include/chipmunk -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/./../external/xxhash -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/./.
./external/nslog -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/./../external/poly2tri -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/./../external/poly2tri/common -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/./
../external/poly2tri/sweep -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/./../external/clipper -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/external/websockets/prebuilt/android/../../include/android -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.an
droid-studio/../cocos2d/external/Box2D/.. -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/external/bullet/.. -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/external/freetype2/prebuilt/android/../../include/android -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/pr
oj.android-studio/../cocos2d/external/freetype2/prebuilt/android/../../include/android/freetype2 -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/external/png/prebuilt/android/../../include/android -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2
d/external/jpeg/prebuilt/android/../../include/android -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/external/tiff/prebuilt/android/../../include/android -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/external/webp/prebuilt/android/../../in
clude/android -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/external/chipmunk/prebuilt/android/../../include -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/external/zlib/prebuilt/android/../../include -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-
studio/../cocos2d/external/recast/.. -II:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/platform/android -II:/Software/ProgramingSoftware/cocos2dx/android-ndk-r12/build//../sources/android/cpufeatures -Ijni -DANDROID -DUSE_FILE32API -Wa,--noexecstac
k -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-extern-c-compat -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS=1 -Wno-extern-c-compat -fexceptions -frtti -DCC_ENABLE_CHIPMUNK_INTEGRATION=1 -std=c++11 -fsigned-char -DCOCOS2D_DEBUG=1 -isystem I:/Software/ProgramingSo
ftware/cocos2dx/android-ndk-r12/build//../platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/include -c jni/../../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp -o ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/MyGame_shared/**/**/**/Classes/AppDelegate.o, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/MyGame_shared/**/**/__/Classes/AppDelegate.o] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `I:/Work/cocos2dx/MyGame/proj.android-studio/app'
Error running command, return code: 2.

Comment: try downloading `android-ndk-r9d` along with the latest  `JDK` version.

Answer (score 0):

That command made everything works for me :

cocos compile -p android --android-studio --app-abi armeabi

But it only gonna compile it for the abi armeabi architecture.